# Geotargeting a blog folder with GWT

Tags: seo, geotargetting

I'm about to launch a blog in a multilingual website.
The website uses geotargeting: site.com/fr/ for france, /be/ for belgium, ch for switzerland, ...
I was wondering if the blog should be run in root level: site.com/blog/
in that case, how the blog could be geotargeted?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should have different URLs for each region/language. For example:

- example.com/fr/blog or
- example.com/be/blog

Or, even:

- example.com/blog/fr or
- example.com/blog/be

That depends on you. The main thing is to separate URLs for different languages/regions.

After you do all this, you should add [hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) attributes. That way you tell Google what version of a URL should be displayed when someone searches in certain language/from certain region.

If you use hreflang, you don't have to set geotargeting in WMT. If you still want to do that, you should add separate folders to WMT as different websites.

Comment: Hi Bojan, Thanks for your reply.
I forgot to mention that the blog will be in only 1 language. does it still have to be in different folders??
Thanks

Comment: In that case, you don't need separate folders or geotargeting for the blog.

Comment: But /blog/ will not be "orphan" folder?
I'm just afraid it wont be well indexed in france as it's my main target...

Comment: Don't worry, it will be fine. Or, you can put it under /fr, if you want to make sure. It's not important how many slashes (folders) is blog away from strong pages, for example home page. It's important how many clicks it takes to get to it.